# Como colocar uma imagem ao lado da outra em uma galeria?

Tags: html, css

Estou criando uma galeria no meu site utilizando html e formatando em css, coloquei cada imagem em uma div e utilizei a tag float para que na visualização da galeria uma imagem ficasse ao lado da outra. Mas esta ficando um espaço em "branco". Abaixo segue a minha formatção em css:

```
.galeria-foto {
    background: #ffffff;
    width:265px;
    height:250px;
    float:left;
    margin:25px;
    padding: 10 auto;
}
```

Comment: Esse espaço em branco é provavelmente por causa de `margin:25px;`.  Podes juntar o HTML para vermos o problema ao vivo?

Comment: O problema estava no espaçamento externo. Já foi solucionado, obrigada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso provavelmente está ocorrendo por causa do espaçamento externo entre as divs. Tente trocar o valor do atributo margin e teste para ver se o problema será resolvido.
Ex:
 margin:20px;

Comment: Muito obrigado, era esse o problema.